# A batch script which will automatically stash my work from current working branch and pull, push to specific branch and create a new branch

Tags: git, batch-file, git-merge

```
@echo off

set working_dir="D:\Projects\NestJsApiProject"
set /P stash_name= Enter stash name: 
set /P branch_name= Enter new branch name: 
set /P commit_des= Enter commit description: 
set /P isFeature= Is it a feature?Y/N: 
set branch_type= features/
if %isFeature%==N (
    set branch_type= bugs/
)
echo %branch_type%
echo %stash_name%
echo %branch_name%
set /P areYouSure= You are going to create a branch named "%branch_type%%branch_name%", are u sure?Y/N:
if %areYouSure%==Y ( 
    cd /D %working_dir%
    git stash save %stash_name%
    git checkout pre-dev
    git pull origin pre-dev
    git stash pop stash@{0}
    git stash save %stash_name%
    git checkout root-branch
    git pull origin root-branch
    git branch %branch_type%%branch_name%
    git checkout %branch_type%%branch_name%
    git stash apply stash@{0}
    git add .
    git commit -m "%branch_name% %commit_des%"
    git push origin %branch_type%%branch_name%
    git checkout pre-dev
    git pull origin pre-dev
    git stash apply stash@{0}
    git add .
    git commit -m "%branch_name%# %commit_des%"
    git push origin pre-dev
)
pause
```

above code solve my problem, but when conflicts occur with some files it just pushes the conflicted files which I don't want, Is there any way to pause the command window if any conflict occurs

Answer (score 2):

So, you can use **`for`** loop and *operators* **`||`** and **`&&`**:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set working_dir="D:\Projects\NestJsApiProject"
set /P stash_name= Enter stash name: 
set /P branch_name= Enter new branch name: 
set /P commit_des= Enter commit description: 
set /P isFeature= Is it a feature?Y/N: 
set branch_type= features/

if /i "!isFeature!" == "N" set branch_type= bugs/
for %%i in (!branch_type!,!stash_name!,!branch_name!)do Echo/%%~i

:Ask_Again
set /P areYouSure= You are going to create a branch named "!branch_type!!branch_name!", are u sure? [Y/N]:

echo/!areYouSure!|"%__APPDIR__%Findstr.exe" /bei "Y  N" >nul || goto :Ask_Again

if /i "!areYouSure!" == "Y" ( 
      cd /D "!working_dir!"
      for %%i in (
      stash save %stash_name%,
      checkout pre-dev,
      pull origin pre-dev,
      stash pop stash@^{0^},
      stash save %stash_name%,
      checkout root-branch,
      pull origin root-branch,
      branch %branch_type%%branch_name%,
      checkout %branch_type%%branch_name%,
      stash apply stash@^{0^}
      add .,
      commit -m "%branch_name% %commit_des%",
      push origin %branch_type%%branch_name%,
      checkout pre-dev,
      pull origin pre-dev,
      stash apply stash@^{0^}
      add .,
      commit -m "%branch_name%# %commit_des%",
      push origin pre-dev 
    )do echo/ Git %%~i || "%__APPDIR__%Timeout.exe" -1 
) else echo/areYouSure = N 
endlocal
```

Test and see the results, if ok, remove:

```
echo/ Git %%~i || "%__APPDIR__%Timeout.exe" -1
```

Read more about...

- **[For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**
- **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**
- **[EnableDelayedExpansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)**
- **[Conditional Execution || && | & operators...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**